# Is this proof really this simple?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\textbf{Question:}$ If $Mdx + Ndy =0$ is exact, then $xMdx+xNdy =0$ is also exact. True or False?

If $M_y = N_x$ then $xM_y \neq xN_x$ because $x$ is a constant when taking partial derivative w.r.t  $y$ and a variable when taking partial derivative w.r.t $x$!

So is this really that simple or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, $0dx+1dy$ is exact, but $xdy$ isn’t even closed…

Comment: You need to show that $d(xM)/dy \ne d(xN)/dx$. It's simple but be precise

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks!